# Existential vs universal quantifier query

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Find Employees who get higher salary than **anyone** in the department 5.

In the above statement "anyone" means for all employees of department 5 or at least one employee of department 5?

Comment: Yes, it means "for all". The query must return the Employee $x$ iff $x$ gets a salary that is higher than the salary of every employee belonging to Dept.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really more a question about English than mathematics, but because it's such a common phrasing in word problems, I'll admit that it in on-topic.

Using "anyone" in this sense means "for all". In other words, if we say "John makes more money than **anyone** in department 5", then there is not a single person in department 5 that makes more money than him. "Anyone" is in this context almost interchangeable with "everyone".

(My gut says the difference is that using "anyone" would mean "no matter which single person you compare him to", and using "everyone" would mean "compared to all the other people at the same time", which *could* mean all the other's salaries *put together*. But I am no linguist, so I might be wrong. Although in a totally different context, like "I can fight anyone in this bar and win" and "I can fight everyone in this bar and win", there is a huge difference.)

In the other case, we would use the word "someone": If we said "John makes more money than **someone** in department 5", then that means that there exists at least one person in department 5 with lower salary than John.

Comment: I understood it now.Thank you.